# How to make dynamic time for schedule in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, schedule

I want to change schedule of notification throw TG bot. I put time in sql and don't know how to change this variable in thread of schedule module. Not it's look like

```
def ScheduleActions():
  updateTime = dataBase.GetCurrentNotificationTime()
  schedule.every().day.at(updateTime).do(send_notification_message)
  while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

scheduleThread = threading.Thread(target=ScheduleActions)
scheduleThread.start()
```

But this way take update time just one time when script running and don't change it before didn't restart bot. Help pls, how to fix it?

Comment: Found a resolution, just need use TAG for every work that we wanna change and stop it, than add again new. Seems like `schedule.every().day.at(updateTime).do(send_notification_message).tag('notification_task')` and then `schedule.clear('notification_task')` and add new task with new time

Comment: There is way too little information in here, coming up with an answer becomes all the more difficult.